# jmockit mockup, getting error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: $MMB

Tags: java, jmockit

I am trying to Mock an application using an Android Platform. Many class use super-classe which are part of the Android classes which are unaccessible to my Unit test, this is why I thought using JMockit would solve my problem. Note that I am using also

org.mockito.Mock and org.powermock.

Here's a simple test I am trying to do in a class with Mockup:

```
// ---------------------------------------
public class Bar {
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("Bar#bar()");
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("do something!");
    }
}

public class BarChild extends Bar {
    public void BarChild() {
        System.out.println("BarChild#bar()");
    }

    public void Call1() {
        doSomething();
    }
}
// ---------------------------------------

@Test
public void testMockUp() throws Exception {

   new MockUp<Bar>() {

        @mockit.Mock
        public void doSomething(){
            System.out.println("do something else");
        }
    };

    BarChild obj1 = new BarChild();
    obj1.Call1();
```

}

// ---------------------------------------

This doesn't work. It generate the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: $MMB  at
>   com.gtechna.officer.ui.widget.CheckableLinearLayoutTest$Bar.doSomething(CheckableLinearLayoutTest.java)
>     at
>   com.gtechna.officer.ui.widget.CheckableLinearLayoutTest$BarChild.Call1(CheckableLinearLayoutTest.java:77)
>     at
>   com.gtechna.officer.ui.widget.CheckableLinearLayoutTest.testIsChecked(CheckableLinearLayoutTest.java:110)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

I am getting the feeling that there is a dependency missing.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue with many tests in my project, and for me it was simply upgrading the jmockit dependency from version 1.23 to 1.28 in my gradle build script, try upgrading it might solve your problem also

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I've resolved by change my mocking.
So, it may happen due to some Invalid Mocking, for a testing purpose comment out the mocking part/method, and re-run your test case. You will surely get some clue.

Sometimes it may happens due to version issue as well, so if not works then upgrade the Jmockit or Junit version.